# Is there a way to parametrize a module on a type or escape a type from a module in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, locally-abstract-type

Is there a way to either parametrize a module on a type or escape a type from a module in OCaml?  Basically, I'd like to write some routines that are parametrized on a floating point type and still have access to the operators like (+.), (-.), etc.  Certainly, we can write a floating point module like

```
module type REAL = sig
    type t
    val real : float->t
    val (+.) : t->t->t
    val (-.) : t->t->t
    val ( *. ) : t->t->t
    val (/.) : t->t->t
end
```

which has a really basic implementation for normal floats

```
module MyReal : REAL = struct
    type t=float
    let real x=x
    let (+.) x y = x+.y  
    let (-.) x y = x-.y
    let ( *. ) x y = x*.y
    let (/.) x y = x/.y
end
```

Then, I tried to use this module locally in a module with the code

```
let double (type real) (module Real:REAL with type t = real) x =
    let open Real in
    x+.x
```

This function has the type that I desire

```
val double : (module REAL with type t = 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

However, if I run it, the compiler will complain

```
# double (module MyReal) 1.0;;
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         MyReal.t
```

Certainly, we can use the injection function from the module

```
# double (module MyReal) (MyReal.real 1.0);;
- : MyReal.t = <abstr>
```

but then the resulting type is abstract and not a float.  Ultimately, I'd like a way to have the function double return an exposed type.  If at all possible, I don't want to use another function within the REAL module to convert `t->float`.  I want the actual type `t` to be exposed somehow.  Also, I'd like a way to do this by using the module locally rather than a functor parameterized on `REAL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave `MyReal` a type constraint too restricted:  `MyReal : REAL`.  It's type `t`'s implementation is hidden by the constraint.  At the use of `MyReal`, `double (module MyReal) 1.0`, the unification of type `t` and `float` fails since you hide the fact `t = float`.

A fix is the following:

```
module MyReal : REAL with type t = float = struct
  ...
end
```

but the best way is to let OCaml infer the most general type for `MyReal` by itself:

```
module MyReal = struct
  ...
end
```

Here, the relationship of `MyReal` and `REAL` is less clear but OCaml's module typing is clever enough to find `MyReal` has an instance of `module REAL with type t = 'a`.